# angularjs error handling executes even without entering data in the form field

Tags: angularjs, forms, error-handling

Why do I get the success message even without entering something or even without touching the field?

```
<div class="form-group"
     ng-class="{'has-error':Form.description.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.description.$valid}">
    <label class="control-label" translate="dashboard.field1"></label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.field1"
           ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20
           type="text" name="description"
           placeholder="Enter your text"/>
    <span class="error text-small block"
          ng-if="Form.description.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
    <span class="error text-small block"
          ng-if="Form.description.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
    <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.description.$valid"> Success!</span>
</div>
```

### update:

this form field is not `required` as you see in my input parameters. I just want to control the input text with min and max, if ever the user wants to put in text so that it meets these requirements; but the field itself should not be required, because when I submit the form, I don't want it to prevent the user from submitting it just because one field was left out.

Comment: can you provide your angularjs version?

Comment: Paste full code. What can I understand from this much? Where is controller? Where is your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the empty is valid, even with the min length. If empty is not valid you should add the `required` attribute.

Or, you can add the `$dirty` on the ng-if. Now it only shows success if the user type something. But, if the user erase the input text the description is still "dirty".

Or, as I suspect is what you need, change the `ng-if="Form.description.$valid && model.field1"`. Now the Success will show only if is valid (3 - 20) and is not empty.

```
<form name="Form">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.description.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.description.$valid}">
  <label class="control-label" translate="dashboard.field1"></label>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.field1" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter your text" />
  <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.description.$error.maxlength">
    Too long!
  </span>
  <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.description.$error.minlength">
    Too short!
  </span>
  <span class="success text-small" 
  ng-if="Form.description.$valid && model.field1"> Success!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: does adding `required`also make the form required? i don't want to do that. this is an optional field.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when your angular bootstraps the form in turn will be replaced with error attributes to elements.To avoid this pitfall for the first time,Use

$dirty:Checks if the element is made dirty

```
 <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.description.$dirty && Form.description.$error.maxlength">
    Too long!
  </span>
```